# ARcore Camera texture is obtained only from Unity Editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, textures, arcore

I am working on a project using ARcore.

I need a real world screen that is visible on the ARcore camera, formerly using the method of erasing UI and capturing.

But it was so slow that I found Frame.CameraImage.Texture in Arcore API

```
Texture2D snap = (Texture2D)Frame.CameraImage.Texture;
```

It worked normally in a Unity Editor environment.

But if you build it on your phone and check it out, Texture is null.

I know this problem is because the CPU is inaccessible on mobile phones.

So I found another way, and I found this one, AcquireCameraImageBytes().

[LoadRawTextureData() not enough data provided error in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55159113/loadrawtexturedata-not-enough-data-provided-error-in-unity)

There were as many problems as in the previous question, but the problem was solved when the YUV format was converted to RGB format.

However, it works normally only in Unity Editor, and when built with a mobile phone, a gray image is output.

[image]

this is my full code

```
namespace GoogleARCore
{
    using System;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;

    public class TestFrameCamera : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private Texture2D m_TextureRender;

        private void Update()
        {
            using (var image = Frame.CameraImage.AcquireCameraImageBytes())     { 
                if(!image.IsAvailable)
                {
                    return;
                }

                _OnImageAvailable(image.Width, image.Height, image.Y, image.Width * image.Height);
            }

        }
        private void _OnImageAvailable(int width, int height, IntPtr pixelBuffer, int bufferSize)
        {

            m_TextureRender = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false, false);
            byte[] bufferYUV = new byte[width * height * 3 / 2];
            bufferSize = width * height * 3 / 2;
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(pixelBuffer, bufferYUV, 0, bufferSize);
            Color color = new Color();
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {

                    float Yvalue = bufferYUV[y * width + x];
                    float Uvalue = bufferYUV[(y / 2) * (width / 2) + x / 2 + (width * height)];
                    float Vvalue = bufferYUV[(y / 2) * (width / 2) + x / 2 + (width * height) + (width * height) / 4];
                    color.r = Yvalue + (float)(1.37705 * (Vvalue - 128.0f));
                    color.g = Yvalue - (float)(0.698001 * (Vvalue - 128.0f)) - (float)(0.337633 * (Uvalue - 128.0f));
                    color.b = Yvalue + (float)(1.732446 * (Uvalue - 128.0f));

                    color.r /= 255.0f;
                    color.g /= 255.0f;
                    color.b /= 255.0f;

                    if (color.r < 0.0f)
                        color.r = 0.0f;
                    if (color.g < 0.0f)
                        color.g = 0.0f;
                    if (color.b < 0.0f)
                        color.b = 0.0f;

                    if (color.r > 1.0f)
                        color.r = 1.0f;
                    if (color.g > 1.0f)
                        color.g = 1.0f;
                    if (color.b > 1.0f)
                        color.b = 1.0f;

                    color.a = 1.0f;
                    m_TextureRender.SetPixel(width - 1 - x, y, color);
                }
            }


            m_TextureRender.Apply();
            this.GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = m_TextureRender;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm just testing this script by adding it to an object that contains Rawimage in the ARCore sample code.

what should i do?

Comment: Grey image or greyscale image? If it is greyscale this is most likely related to Texture format even though you use  `RGBA32`

Comment: @AliKanat but RGB color is in Unity Editor.